# Running TensorFlow demo model on Windows

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have installed tensorflow on Windows 7 using

```
C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Then to check if it is working fine, I did:

```
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

It printed "Hello, TensorFlow!"

So everything seems working fine.

But now I am trying to locate
 "tensorflow/models/"

but there is no such directory. Contents of tensorflow directory at my machine are presented in this image
[image: Contents of tensorflow directory are presented in this image]

I don't know how to find or install tensorflow/models/,  so that I can use already trained models for my problem.

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you looking for this: https://github.com/tensorflow/models

Comment: I want to go to the folder "tensorflow/models/image/imagenet" that contains "classify_image.py" python file. I am new to tensorflow, as per my understanding I can use already trained models present in this folder. My installation of tensorflow doesn't contain this folder.

Comment: clone 'models' project from tensorflow repository.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone tensorflow models for the path you are mentioning

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```

And locate: tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py